# Haskell class Show

Tags: haskell

I want to print a matrix. For example:

```
       data Matrix = Matr [[Int]]

       instance Show Matrix where
                show(Matr (x:xs)) = show(x)++"\n"++show(head(xs))

       Example of use:

                Matr [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
                [1,2,3]
                [4,5,6]
                [7,8,9] -- this line is not showed on my instance Show
```

How can I show all the elements in the Matrix? Thanks.

Comment: You know `head` takes the first element of a list, right?  That's why the rest of your matrix isn't being shown.  Luckily, there's no need to write an explicitly recursive show function if you don't want to; Haskell has lots of useful combinators to capture such patterns for you.  For instance, try `show (Matr xs) = intercalate "\n" (map show xs)`.  (`intercalate` is a useful combinator from `Data.List`.)

Comment: I tried with this: show(Matr (x:xs)) = show(x)++"\n"++show(Matr (xs)).
But it has an error: Program error: pattern match failure: v2897_v2908 (Matr [])

Comment: You need to include a base case for your recursion; here that means providing a clause of the form `show (Matr []) = ...`; probably just `show (Matr []) = ""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must iterate over all elements

```
instance Show Matrix where
  show (Matr d) = print d
    where print [] = []
          print (x:xs) = show x ++ "\n" ++ print xs
```

another way

```
instance Show Matrix where
  show (Matr d) = concatMap ((++"\n").show) d
```

Comment: Also, note the `intercalate` function (from `Data.List`) that @Fixnum points out above, `show (Matr d) = intercalate "\n" . map show $ d`.